# Rails 3 functional test - 'get()'can't access a controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, get, functional-testing

In my project, stories belong to users and typically all story access is through nested resourcing, with the exception of an action to show a global list of all stories. In my routes.rb file I have:

```
 resources :users do
    resources :stories
 end
 match "/all_stories" => "stories#all_stories"
```

the `match` statement generates the following route:

```
all_stories   /all_stories(.:format)    {:controller=>"stories", :action=>"all_stories"}
```

In my `stories_controller.rb` file I have an action called:  `all_stories`.

```
  def all_stories
    @stories = Story.all
  end
```

From my view I'm calling `link_to` in this manner:

```
<%= link_to  "All Stories", all_stories_path %>
```

resulting in this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stories", :user_id=>nil, 
:id=>#<Story id: 1, title: "test story 01", desc: "Edited desc for test story 01",
activity: 20, created_at: "2011-11-28 01:07:08", updated_at: "2011-11-28 01:26:31", 
user_id: 5>}
```

In my `stories_controller_test.rb` the following GET calls for `:all_stories` generate the listed errors:

```
get( 'all_stories' )
Undefined method `story_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010430da18>:0x00000101789d10>

get( :all_stories )
undefined method `story_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000102a178b0>:0x00000100ee9cc8>

get( '/all_stories' )
No route matches {:controller=>"stories", :action=>"/all_stories"}

get( {:action=>"all_stories"} )
No route matches {:controller=>"stories", :action=>"{:action=>\"all_stories\"}"}
```

On the first two, there is no 'story_path" because stories are nested under users.  Not sure what is happening on the next two.  What syntax can I use to `get` the `all_stories` action in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the route to

```
match "/all_stories" => "stories#all_stories", :as => :all_stories
```

Then in your code, you can reference the `all_stories_path` or the `all_stories_url`

Comment: Solomon, thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.  I made your change and set my link_to/get methods to reference: all_stories_path. My link_to statement (in a view) errors out with:  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stories", :user_id=>nil, :id=>#<Story id: 1, title: "test story 01", desc: "Edited desc for test story 01", activity: 20, created_at: "2011-11-28 01:07:08", updated_at: "2011-11-28 01:26:31", user_id: 5>}     My functional test errors out with:   No route matches {:controller=>"stories", :action=>"/all_stories"}

Comment: Try putting your match all stories line above the resources section. If that doesn't work, what is your link_to statement (maybe there is a typo)? Lastly, why don't you add your controller code, because maybe there's something in there...

Comment: I'm looking at the error again in your comment, and it seems to point to an issue in the link_to. In the all_stories_path, you shouldn't be passing a story as an :id parameter. Maybe it's not a problem with the :all_stories path, as much as a problem in the row you are showing for each individual story. Try not displaying any information on the page to check if the page is routing correctly.

Comment: Solomon - agree that the error message points to something strange.  I've edited the question with the all_stories action from my controller and my link_to statement.  Appreciate you looking at this.

Comment: Solomon - Found the issue thanks to your suggestions.  The link_to that I added to the question above functions fine (your troubleshooting tip on showing a blank page showed me this.)  The problem was in the link_to statements for each row in the target view (all_stories.html.erb.)  I had a '@user' variable in them but no '@user' variable declared in the controller (stupid copy/paste error.)  In the end I needed to create a new action and view for a single "@user-less" story and ensure that my link_to (pointing to this single-story view) did not contain a '@user' reference.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

i got this problem but i was able to solve it using @controller
use @contr